# Passing a Date Parameter in XML inside another XML element on config file

Tags: c#, xml, xslt-1.0, config

I am a bit new to understanding XML config files however this is what I know so far:
We have a config file that is used by a C# based .exe and gets parsed to move files from one location to another.

As of right now we use this as a standard for creating a file element and destinations/source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       ...miscellaneous XML config nodes

    <FileLocation SourcePath="\\SERVER" DestinationPath="\\SERVER" ArchivePath="\\SERVER">
            <File>
              <FileKeyword>Company_Memo.txt</FileKeyword>
              <FileDestination>Memo.txt</FileDestination>
            </File>
    </FileLocation>
```

So as you can see the  scans the source folder and renames it to whatever you put in  then moves it to the destination directory.

**Question:** I've been trying to figure out how to append a date parameter, preferable get date, or the full name of the file it finds in  instead of setting an arbitrary name. Something like this:

```
<FileLocation SourcePath="\\SERVER" DestinationPath="\\SERVER" ArchivePath="\\SERVER">
        <File>
          <FileKeyword>Company_Memo.txt</FileKeyword>
          <FileDestination>Memo<Date></Date>.txt</FileDestination>
        </File>
</FileLocation>
```

Ive looked into using and xsl node but I can't figure out if it is possible.

The executable cannot be modified without a dev modification request and I was hoping there would be a way around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need a dev modification request.  Your devs have already set the method that the xml gets parsed, and unless they have set it up to take a date parameter, you won't be able to just add one using the XML config file.  Even if they did, you're going to have to ask them how to use it, as it is a proprietary system and nobody outside your company will have knowledge on how to use it so that it will be parsed correctly by your software.